# Get access to data of not declared class directly

Tags: c++, class

We have a class Model inside which is a function which returns an instance of class Mesh with parameters. In a class Mesh has a constructor with parameters, and a few public fields:

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model(string path)
    {
        this->loadModel(path);
    }

    Mesh loadModel(string path)
    {
        vector<GLfloat> vertices;
        vector<GLuint> indices;
        ...
        return Mesh (vertices, indices);
    }
};
class Mesh 
{
public:
    vector<GLfloat> vertices;
    vector<GLuint> indices;

    Mesh(vector<GLfloat> vertices, vector<GLuint> indices)
    {
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->indices = indices;
        this->loadMesh();
    }

    void loadMesh()
    { 
        //sending data to OpenGL
    }
};

int main()
{
   Model model("folder/...");
   return 0;
}
```

In main function we declare only Model class. Mesh class was created on the fly and sends data to OpenGL. 
How can we get access to fields of class Mesh (verticies, indicies) in main function? Or it is no longer there? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Model::loadModel` returns a `Mesh` object.  Since the line

```
this->loadModel(path);
```

does nothing with that return value, its information is lost when that returned object is destroyed.